# How to mark paper documents before scanning to simplify OCR sorting?

Tags: ocr

My business generates a lot of handwritten notes that get scanned and sorted into clients' files. Each file has a unique 5-digit numeric code, which is handwritten on the page before scanning. Our handwriting is inconsistent enough that OCR doesn't work well for identifying the file number .

Is there a clever way to quickly manually label a paper document with information that will be easily recognized after scanning? We can't pre-print a barcode ahead of time, and it needs to be simple for office staff to do.

I'm looking for a simple way for several non-technical people to quickly add information by hand to facilitate the automatic sorting of scans.

We can pre-print the pages with additional graphics, if it would help the OCR process. For example, we could print something like a Scantron form in a specific part of the page.

Is there an easy solution for this?

Comment: Are those numbers assigned by people or coming from a computer system?

Comment: When we add a new client, a unique 5-digit number is assigned to that person. We can write the number on the paper before scanning, and when the number is identified by the OCR software, the scanned document will be stored with the rest of that client's records. For now, it's manual: someone looks for the handwritten file number and sorts the PDF into place.

Comment: Wouldn't a 5x10 scantron matrix at the top of the page work? Easy for non-technical people to use, and they could still (at least for an initial period) also hand-write the 5-digit code. If the OCR matches the scantron with the hand-written code it stores the file automatically. If it doesn't, it keeps the file in a separate folder for manual checking. This way you can iron out any kinks first, before you trust it.

Comment: @Anthony that's probably the simplest. I'll look into setting this up.

Comment: Other option could be - in case you fill the forms near a computer - to have a label printer and quickly print the number and stick it on the form.

Comment: This question is pretty similar to https://superuser.com/questions/1808322/scanning-using-ocr#comment2838393_1808322